# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'innerHTML' of null even when I place my script code inside <body> tag

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, typeerror

I am calling a function in JavaScript as shown

```
var count = 0;
function resetGroupsSelector(groupId){
//alert(groupId);
console.log("search_report_form:"+groupId)
//alert("search_report_form:"+groupId)
var id = "search_report_form:"+groupId;
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML("HI");
}
```

But I am getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'innerHTML' of null

error. I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: Unquote id: `document.getElementById("id").innerHTML("HI");` It should be: `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "HI";`

Comment: document.getElementById(id).innerHTML("HI"); Is this the correct method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple syntax error:

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML("HI");
```

Should be changed to this:

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "HI";
                        ^^           ^^^^^^^
```

Don't forget to remove the quotes from `id` since it is a *variable*, so you want to make sure that you're passing the variable instead of the *literal string* `"id"`

Comment: Still need to unquote to `id` as it is variable not attribute value.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal.  Thank you.